# There is any way to log all mongodb query into file in nodejs?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

There is any way to log all MongoDB query into a file

Answer (score 1):

Enable the profiler in MongoDB Database.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/